# Convergence of complex series $\sum_{n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + i^n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

So I have $\sum_{n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + i^n}$. I can find that $|n^2 + i^n| \ge |n^2| - |i^n| = n^2 - 1$ which gives me that $\frac{1}{|n^2 + i^n|} \le \frac{1}{n^2 - 1}$. But what I really want now is that $\frac{1}{n^2 -1}$ converges so that I can abuse the absolute convergence theorem and comparison method to show convergence for my original series.

Small tangent, in my Dif. Eq. class we discuss solutions that approach $\infty$ in finite time ($x^a, a \gt 1$). I was wondering if that could be used to say that $x^a, a\lt -1$ would therefore approach $\frac{1}{\infty}$, or $0$, in finite time. And if this would be the same as proving that the series did converge.

Either way, some help wrapping up this demonstration that $\sum_{n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + i^n}$ does converge would be very helpful, I'm not very good with limits as they are harder to conceptualize. Thank you.

Comment: It is well known that $\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^2  - 1}}} $ converges (it converges to $0$).

Comment: @Gary: how can a sum of positive terms converge to zero ?

Comment: Note that the lower limit of summation tends to infinity.

Comment: What is the variable of summation here?  I think $i$ is supposed to be the variable. It is  not the complex number $i$.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the facts that $\frac{1}{n^2-1}$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{(n/2)^2}=\frac{4}{n^2}$ and that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (there are at least [fourteen proofs](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf) for that).

Alternatively, you may apply [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe's_test) to the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\ge2}=\left\{\frac{1}{n^2-1}\right\}_{n\ge2}$: since
$$
n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)
=n\left(\frac{(n+1)^2-1}{n^2-1}-1\right)
=n\left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2-1}\right)
=\frac{2n^2+n}{n^2-1}>2,
$$
the infinite series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n$ converges.